# About KStream join KTable in kafka stream

Tags: join, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to join two streams, one as KStream, another as KTable.
However, when I send a message to stream, a message to table, then join operation does not occur, when I send a message to stream, join does occur, why is that?

Comment: Hi, please add the code of Topology, and can you describe how you send messages in these two scenario? KStream-KTable join product output messages only when KTable has the data.